# intellij not honoring .editorconfig

Tags: intellij-idea, editorconfig

I have a code block being auto-formatted as:

```
            .withStuff(ImmutableList.of(Stuff.builder().withName("Animaniacs").build(),
                Stuff.builder().withName("Pinky and the Brain").build()))
            .build());
```

That ideally I want idea to auto format as:

```
            .withStuff(ImmutableList.of(
                Stuff.builder().withName("Animaniacs").build(),
                Stuff.builder().withName("Pinky and the Brain").build()
            ))
            .build());
```

I doubt I can get exactly what I'm after, it seems idea is failing to honor several settings in the .editorcofig:

```
ij_java_call_parameters_new_line_after_left_paren = true
ij_java_call_parameters_right_paren_on_new_line = true
ij_java_call_parameters_wrap = split_into_lines
ij_java_keep_line_breaks = true
```

Can anyone advise how to fix this?

Comment: Please try to delete these settings from the .editorconfig file and check the following solution https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134661#focus=Comments-27-4664085.0-0 .

Answer (score -1):

If you put a line-break before `ImmutableList.of` the default formatting will give you this:

```kotlin
            .withStuff(
                ImmutableList.of(
                    Stuff.builder().withName("Animaniacs").build(),
                    Stuff.builder().withName("Pinky and the Brain").build()
                )
            ).build());
```

which is not exactly what you wanted but it is much nicer than your first example and it aligns the list items under each other like you wanted.